# How to create customize app telegram using API?

Tags: android, api, telegram, tdlib

I want to build an app that continues an only one group maybe with API. 
Someone can guide me with this, please?
It's for an Educational app.

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to work with a server.

On your server, you host a database and an API. You can use the database to save the users and the messages. You should also send your push notifications with this server. You can send push using [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?gclid=CjwKCAiAnfjyBRBxEiwA-EECLFW5M1GH7ijZorFVcSDrMRCoICVgUqHYGz3OYEbrJKC5ynr-msccDhoC-vUQAvD_BwE), but I personally had some problems with it and switched to [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/).

In your APP you can show the different messages using a ListView with custom list items. To communicate between server and app you can use a [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) request.

Some time ago I wrote nearly the same app. I would recommend you to use a server with an API (a simple PHP API is enough).

Comment: Are you have a tutorial for me?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a tutorial for you.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can find something on the internet.  For example, this one could work: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-make-a-personal-chat-application-like-whatsapp-fda6dd4bcb5b